# Why is heparin gel not used or sold in the united states?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, different-national-health

[Topical heparins are widely used in Europe for the prevention and treatment of local symptoms associated with peripheral vascular disorders.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18783299)  Why is this not used in the USA?  Why is it not sold?  What if a patient is interested in using this?

Comment: It probably hasn’t been approved by the FDA. That doesn’t mean that it got rejected due to concerns, some medication has just not yet applied for approval (or is in the midst of the approval process). It might be worth checking out if there is a FDA legislation about it.

Comment: To add to @Narusan's comment, sometimes pharmaceutical companies don't even apply for FDA approval in the US for strategic marketing reasons. If they don't apply, obviously it won't be approved.